# sqlite3 query not returning results in a function

Tags: python, sqlite

Function using **sqlite3** to bring back data from a table and return #results based on criteria is only returning zero. Running the #function through Visual Studio brings back the expected results but #when I try to run it from the terminal it is interpreting the table #as being an empty list.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test2.db')
cur = con.cursor()
```

small table to illistrate the problem. Table output is `[('Jane', 300.0), ('Joe', 100.0), ('Joe', 50.0)]`

```
total_bal = """SELECT name, amount FROM customers2"""

user_name = input("What is your name? ")

def account_balance(name):
    cur.execute(total_bal)
    table = cur.execute(total_bal)
    total = 0
    name = user_name
    for t in table:

        if t[0] == name:
            total += t[1]            
    return total
print(account_balance(user_name))
```

expecting to return 150 `if user_name input = 'Joe' or 300 if 'Jane'`

Comment: When you run the code from the terminal, does `test2.db` exist in the current directory?  (sqlite3 allows you to connect to a nonexistent file, but it treats it as a new empty database.)

Comment: What gives `print(name)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon the test2.db file and the .py file are in the same directory.


even more odd running the code from the text editor outputs this, almost like the text editor is storing the table info somehow.


>>> user_name = "Jeff"
>>> 
>>> def account_balance(name):
...     cur.execute(total_bal)
...     table = cur.execute(total_bal)
...     total = 0
...     name = user_name
...     for t in table:
...         if t[0] == name:
...             total += t[1]
...     return total
... 
>>> print(account_balance(user_name))
150.0

Comment: sorr for the atrocious formatting on that.

Comment: @stovfl print name gives me "Joe" if i input Joe with a len of 3. I get the same issue even if I assign user_name explicitly.

Comment: @JeffR: ***"print name gives me "Joe""***: Now, verify it all together with `print('if {} == {}'.format(t[0], name))` just before the `if ...` line.

Comment: Can you add the line `import os; print(os.getcwd())` and run the code in both environments (Visual Studio and terminal) and show us both outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just do this with your query and avoid the account balance function all together.

```py
statement = "SELECT name, account FROM customers2 WHERE name = ?;"
name = input("Enter your name: ")
cur.execute(statement, (str(name),))
results = cur.fetchone()
if results:
   print(f"Name: {results[0]}\nAccount Balance: {results[1]}"
else:
   print("Your name is not in the database")
```

Comment: if you do print(results) it is giving me an empty list on your second solution. Any idea what could be causing that?

I forgot that I already tried your first solution assigning the variable to the the cur.fetchall(). Still returning 0 when I run from the command line. That solution also brings back the right amount when I run it from the text editor.

Comment: My guess would be the name you entered does not exactly match a record in your database.

Comment: Make sure you are running the script in the same working directory as your database. If you do not want to do that; import os, and add ```os.chdir("path to db directory")```at the top of your script. My guess is that python is not using your pre created database and is creating a new one.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), you can iterate directly over the result from `execute()`; you do not have to call `fetch`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've found that to be true. It doesn't fix my output here unfortunately. It seems like the execute isn't giving me an actual list as it is returning as an empty list. Very confusing

Comment: I did not know you could do that, very interesting! I will update my answer. @Jeff R did you try my suggestion regarding the current working directory?

Comment: @RobertKearns Going to check it in the morning with fresh eyes. Been looking at this for several hours. Thanks for the help.